# Grep and increase value

Tags: linux, bash, unix, time, grep

I would like to know how to grep only the Atoms.Timestep in the file and increment the value of the Timestep? For example add 200.

I tried to use bash file but its not working.

```
Atoms. Timestep: 0
1 76.494 75.0579 73.6777
2 75.5756 74.3821 74.9533
3 75.4282 72.7064 74.7586
4 74.6055 72.4862 73.3068
5 75.4501 73.045 71.9846
6 75.6282 74.7559 72.2756
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post the code that you have already tried, the output that you get and the output that you expect instead. In this way it is much more likely that you get an answer quickly. Please see also how to produce a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is the output expected?

Comment: the expected output the value of the Timestep from 0 to 200                                                                                                Atoms. Timestep: 200
1 76.494 75.0579 73.6777
2 75.5756 74.3821 74.9533
3 75.4282 72.7064 74.7586
4 74.6055 72.4862 73.3068
5 75.4501 73.045 71.9846
6 75.6282 74.7559 72.2756

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cat your_file | grep -Eo "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|[0-9]*" | sort | awk '{print $1+200}'
```

**Output:**

```
200
201
202
203
204
205
206
271.985
272.276
272.486
272.706
273.045
273.307
273.678
274.382
274.606
274.756
274.759
274.953
275.058
275.428
275.45
275.576
275.628
276.494
```

But that will round up to 3 digits.

The line below will keep 4 decimal points.

```
cat your_file | grep -Eo "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|[0-9]*" | sort | awk '{printf "%.4f\n", $1+200}'
```

Output:

```
200.0000
200.0000
201.0000
202.0000
203.0000
204.0000
205.0000
206.0000
271.9846
272.2756
272.4862
272.7064
273.0450
273.3068
273.6777
274.3821
274.6055
274.7559
274.7586
274.9533
275.0579
275.4282
275.4501
275.5756
275.6282
276.4940
```

Comment: `cat | grep | sort | awk`, uhms, this looks like too many pipes. For a start, `grep ... file` does the same as `cat file | grep ...`.